# Exercise from textbook: verify KKT conditions for a quadratic programme

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming, karush-kuhn-tucker

I am struggling with Exercise 7.3 in Cornuejols & Tutuncu's *Optimization Methods in Finance* (1st edition, 2006) [[PDF]](http://web.math.ku.dk/~rolf/CT_FinOpt.pdf):

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & f(x) := x_1x_2 + x_1^2 + \frac{3}{2}x_2^2 + 2x_3^2 + 2x_1 + x_2 + 3x_3\\ \text{subject to} & g_1(x) := x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 1\\ & g_2(x) := x_1 - x_2  = 0\\ & h_i(x) := x_i \geq 0 \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq 3\end{array}$$

The exercise asks to show that $$ x^\star = (.5, .5, 0)$$ is an optimal solution by verification of the KKT-conditions.

Let $y_1, y_2$ and $s_1, s_2, s_3$ denote the multipliers corresponding to the $g_i$ and $h_i$. We have $s_1 = s_2 = 0$ because $s_ix_i = 0$. Hence the first (necessary) condition to verify is that there exist $s_3 \geq 0, y_1, y_2$ such that

$$\nabla f = y_1\nabla g_1 + y_2\nabla g_2 + s_3\nabla h_3,$$

where all gradients are evaluated at $x^\ast$.

This leads to the linear system (unless I made a mistake...):

$$
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    2x_1 + x_2 + 2\\
    x_1 + 3x_2+1\\
    4x_3 + 3\\
    \end{matrix}\right) = 
    \left(\begin{matrix}
    7/2\\
    3\\
    3\\
    \end{matrix}\right) = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 1  & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 0 \\
1 & 0  & 1
\end{matrix}\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
s_3
\end{matrix}\right),
$$

but this has a solution $s_3 < 0$.
Please help me see where I went wrong.

Comment: Lagrange multipliers for equality constraints aren’t sign restricted.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not following -- $s_3$ relates to $h_3$, which is an inequality constraint (and hence sign restricted, no?).

Comment: I attempted solving this myself and found $s_3=-1/4$ which cannot be correct. Perhaps there is an error in the problem?

Comment: My apologies- I thought you were putting the sign restriction on the equality constraint Lagrange multipliers.  Another issue here is that the sign restriction changes depending on whether you're maximizing or minimizing the objective and whether the inequality constraints are $\leq$ or $\geq$ constraints and whether you've got $\nabla f(x)$ and the $\nabla g_{i}(x)$ terms on the same side of the equation or on opposite sides..  It appears that you have the sign restriction backwards for this problem.

Comment: @Math1000 - Thanks for the second pair of eyes. $s_3 = -1/4$ is indeed my solution too.

Comment: @BrianBorchers - I've cross-checked with the entry on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions#Necessary_conditions). I am minimizing $f$, my constraints are $g_i \geq 0$ (unlike on Wikipedia), but my $\nabla g_i$ is also on the other side (unlike on Wikipedia). So both minus-signs cancel, and my $s_i$ (the $\mu_i$ on Wikipedia) should remain positive. It could indeed be an error in the textbook problem but I am not bold enough to claim this without backup...

Comment: @SebastianS you got the sign right, there is an error in the book.

Comment: @LinAlg - Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot solve the KKT conditions for $x^*=(0.5, 0.5, 0)$, that solution is not optimal. There is an error in the assignment.

Since $Q$ is positive definite, there is just one optimal solution. With optimization software (Python code added below) I found the solution to be $\hat{x}\approx(0.47826, 0.47826, 0.04348)$. Note that $\hat{x}$ is a feasible solution because it satisfies the constraints. With this approximate solution you can easily prove that the solution $x^*$ given in the book is suboptimal, because its objective value is 2.375, whereas $\hat{x}$ has objective value 2.3695..., which is better.

```
import numpy
import cvxopt
Q = 2*matrix([ [1, .5, 0.0], [.5, 1.5, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 2.0] ])
p = matrix([2.0, 1.0, 3.0])
G = matrix([[-1.0,0.0,0.0],[0.0,-1.0,0.0],[0.0,0.0,-1.0]])
h = matrix([0.0,0.0,0.0])
A = matrix([[1.0, 1.0], [1.0, -1.0], [1.0, 0.0]])
b = matrix([1.0, 0.0])
sol=solvers.qp(Q, p, G, h, A, b)
```